# Question related to page-user.tpl.php

Tags: theming

Is there a way to tell when we are in the /user/1/edit page vs in the /user/1 page when inside the template file page-user.tpl.php?

Are there any of the $variables that I can check?

I think I would rather check this, than create a nearly identical template file called page-user-edit.tpl.php. Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Check for `arg(2)` to differentiate both paths. [Arg() function docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/arg/6).

In case `user/1` arg(2) will be Null

Incase `user/1/edit` arg(2) will be 'edit'